# Which shell command returns Java's home path?

Tags: shell, command-line, java, maven

I'm aware of the *which* command but when I run it on Java, I get the following path:

```
$ which java
/bin/java
```

What I'm looking for, I think, is the Java path I get when I run the following Maven command:

```
$ mvn -version
Apache Maven 3.6.3
Java version: 11.0.14.1, vendor: Ubuntu, runtime: /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64
Default locale: en, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "5.13.0-1021-aws", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

Isn't the latter (/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64) the correct Java home path?
If so, which command would directly return it?

Running the *java version* command doesn't return any paths.

Comment: `/bin/java` is probably a symlink.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`readlink -f /bin/java` will trace the symlink all the way down to the actual executable. The result you get will be something of the form `/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java`. Omit the `/bin/java` part at the end to get the JDK/JRE home path.